# Converting MySQL queried JSON to Object

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, arrays, json

I have been struggling to convert the MySQL query JSON object below into a normal object. Any ideas on how to go about this? I have been trying for a long time but cant seem to find a solution. Thanks for your time.

```
{"lectures":"{\"id\":1,\"lecture_id\":9,\"school\":\"University\",\"location\":\"London\",\"class\":\"21\",\"subject\":\"Advanced Maths\",\"teacher_name\":\"John Andrews\",\"teacher_email\":\"test@yahoo.com\",\"start_time\":\"18:00\",\"end_time\":\"21:00\",\"date\":\"Wed Apr 14 2021\",\"room_uuid\":\"0b762ce4-eb04-4068-a199-f32bdb694d47\",\"room_password\":\"pw\",\"additional_notes\":\"Bring protractor\"}"}
```

My code is below.

```js
con.query("SELECT column FROM table", (err, latestEnrolment) => {
        if(err) throw err;
    });

    try{
        await res.render('ejs', { 
            latestEnrolment
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried this : `JSON.parse(response.lectures)` Here response is the value above

Comment: What's the problem with this JSON? normal legitimate value...

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I tried your solution but got SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: Hi Akina, I would need to use it for a table later, but can not use it due to the unusable form

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
let lecturesString = object['lectures'].replace("\\", "")

let lecturesObj = JSON.parse(lecturesString)

console.log(lecturesObj)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I replaced 'object['lectures'] with the query result 'queryResponse' but got an error TypeError: queryResponse.replace is not a function

Comment: con.query("SELECT lectures FROM account'", (err, latestEnrolment) => {
        if(err) throw err;
    });

    try{
        await res.render('ejs', { 
            latestEnrolment
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }